# Identify customer who made purchase using braintree dropin ui

Tags: javascript, php, braintree, gateway

We are experimenting with Braintree's dropin ui to collect payment from customers.

We are able to receive payment from customers (and arrive at the 'success' page) and now need to identify which customer made the payment and reflect it on our database.

Custom fields don't seem to work with dropin ui to pass our client id, etc.

Is there any variable on the 'success' page of the dropin ui that identifies the user who made the purchase in the checkout page?

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

**Accessing the customer associated with a transaction**

The [`Braintree_Transaction`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/transaction/) record returned within a [`$result`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/result-objects/) object does have a [`customerDetails`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/transaction/#customer_details) property. Therefore, the customer who made the transaction can be identified:

```
$result->transaction->customerDetails
```

**Associating a new customer with a transaction**

You can [create a customer, store their payment method, and create a transaction at once](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/#new-customer-with-new-payment-method) using only [`Braintree_Transaction::sale()`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/). Simply pass in the payment method nonce that you received from your client and set `storeInVaultOnSuccess` to `true`. Optionally, you can specify a customer ID and other [customer parameters](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/#customer). (*If you do not specify a customer ID, the gateway will create one for you.*)

```
$result = Braintree_Transaction::sale([
  'amount' => '10.00',
  'paymentMethodNonce' => nonceFromTheClient,
  'customer' => [
    'id' => 'a_customer_id'
  ],
  'options' => [
    'storeInVaultOnSuccess' => true,
  ]
]);
```

**Associating an existing customer with a transaction**

When using the Drop-in UI, you may specify which *returning* customer made a transaction by including that customer's ID when you generate a [client token](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/client-token/generate):

> The Drop-in UI supports presenting returning customers with their saved payment methods. To generate a token for a customer in your vault provide the customer's ID.<sup>[1](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/client-token/generate/#specify-a-customer-id)</sup>

```
$clientToken = Braintree_ClientToken::generate([
    "customerId" => $aCustomerId
]);
```

*You may only specify IDs for customers that already exist in your vault.*